# How to correct my $PATH?

Tags: macos, rspec, environment-variables

I use Mac OS X and i have some profile and bash_profile. Here are the contents of my file :

```
cat ~/.profile 
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

and

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) 
export M2_HOME=/Users/myName/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5
export GIT_HOME=/usr/local/git
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$GIT_HOME/bin


### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

MYSQL=/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

### ADDED FOR SUBLIME SYMLINK
export PATH=/usr/bin/local/bin:$PATH
```

Here is the content of $PATH :

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin/local/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-3.4.0/lib/rspec.rb:/usr/bin/local/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Users/myname/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/myname/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I don't understand why i have this /Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-3.4.0/lib/rspec.rb in the path. How i could remove it ? I cannot see it neither in ~/.profile nor in ~/.bash_profile.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the "rbenv init" add to the path?

Comment: bash ignores .profile if .bash_profile exists, so .profile is irrelevant. But the PATH additions in .bash_profile appear to have been done twice, with some other additions ("/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-3.4.0/lib/rspec.rb") in between. Where that's coming from I'm not sure. Do you have a .bashrc file?

Answer (score 1):

That's a binstub for RSpec being set by rbenv.

1. use `rbenv rehash` to make sure your `.rbenv/versions/...` folder is current
2. Make sure you're using ruby 2.2.2 via rbenv by running `rbenv shell 2.2.2`
3. `gem uninstall -a rspec`
4. `rbenv rehash`
5. Reload shell.

You should only have one of this line:
`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

You've also got a ton of duplication in your $PATH it's likely your bashrc files are being loaded multiple times, or that you're running another RC script you're not aware of:

```
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-3.4.0/lib/rspec.rb
/Users/myname/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin
/Users/myname/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin
/bin
/opt/ImageMagick/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/local/bin
/usr/bin/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/heroku/bin
/usr/local/heroku/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/sbin
```

See also:
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs
http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/02/07/rbenv-and-bundler/